# Extracting JSON like data from pandas data frame to separate columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is sample data:

```xml
{"Navbar":{"appId":"metaManagement","masked":true},"control":{"control":"accountNumber","id":"6789","value":null,"masked":false}}

{"Navbar":{"appId":"metaManagement","masked":true},"control":{"control":"accountNumber","id":"12345","value":null,"masked":false}}
```

I have searched many blogs & platforms but having no proper solution available. Can I fetch appID into separate column? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
>>> from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
>>> d = {"Navbar":{"appId":"metaManagement","masked":"true"},"control":{"control":"accountNumber","id":"6789","value":"null","masked":"false"}}
>>> json_normalize(d)
     Navbar.appId Navbar.masked control.control control.id control.value control.masked
0  metaManagement          true   accountNumber       6789          null          false
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it if data is in pandas dataframe column.

```
    import json

    for i in range(len(df)):
        try:
           data = json.loads(df['jsonColumn'][i])

           df['jsonColumn1_Revised'][i] = data['Navbar']['appId']
           df['jsonColumn2_Revised'][i] = data['Navbar']['masked']
        except:
           continue
```